# facebook log in window comes even after "You have already authorized ***" screen

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm making an IOS app with Facbook support in Unity. 
When I run FB.Login(), and the user has authorized the app already before, I get the "You have already authorized ***" screen. That makes sense.

But then, I still get the "Log in" window, which I don't think should happen. That "Log in" window is also set up strange, in a way that the window is in portrait mode, but the keyboard is in landscape mode (rotated 90 deegrees)
Besides, if I exit that Log in window, I'm still logged in fine - so that tells me the Log in window really shouldn't happen.

here some code, there's not much actually:

At the very beginning, on one object's Awake function I'm running this: `FB.Init(SetInit, OnHideUnity);`

And then, when the problem happens is this function:

```
FB.Login("user_friends", LoginCallback);
```

The LoginCallback is an empty function:

```
void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
{
}
```

Comment: show us some code behind the login window apperiance and your fb login

Comment: sure - just added some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's fixed!
I simply updated Facebook SDK from 6.0.0 to 6.1.0